# Not able to post Application with Xcode 4.6.2, it says "Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK."

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm not able to post Application with Xcode 4.6.2, while uploading it is giving me error "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK". What SDK would it work with?

Comment: As of the 1st febuary all apps need to be build using Xcode 5 and optimized for iOS 7. https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a

Comment: read your developer account emails!

Answer (score 5):

i think that should be arrived this email:

[image]

from 1 february, the apps must be built with Xcode 5

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your xcode 4.6.3 to xcode 5 and make app support for iOS 7 also. then only appstore validate your app